# Email in Digital Signature

Tags: digital-signature

How do you add an email to your digital signature details?

Digital signature details are found when a file is signed for instance by VeriSign. You then right-click on the file and choose "Digital Signatures" from the tab. You can then select the Name of the signer and select the "Details" button.

[image]

I can't find this anywhere. Even Microsoft has left this field blank, but I need to know where to add it in. Anyone? Thanks!
-jp

[image]

Comment: programmatic or manual would be fine. i just can't find anything on the web about it.

Comment: I suspect this comes from the signing certificate, which means you would have had to have included an email address in the certificate request you sent to your CA - and they would have to be happy to include it in the response rather than stripping it out. If it is in the signing certificate then you can't add one in without invalidating your CA's signature on your certificate.

Comment: Thanks Rup!  I'll ask verisign about ours and see. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the official VeriSign answer:

> Its normal for email address not to appear in the email address filed, the certificate does not validate the organization's email address. The e-mail address always appears as "not available" when viewing properties of signed code. This is because the certificate validates the organization but requires no information about the e-mail address of the organization. Thus, we have validated the organization, but have not validated the e-mail. This in no way lessens the value or usefulness of your ID.

So there you have it...